# Quitar Comillas a numeros de un JSON con expresiones regulares en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, postman

Tengo el siguiente `JSON`:

```json
"impuesto" : {
    "currency" : "CLP",
    "amount" : "100.000"
}
```

Como sería la expresión regular para eliminar las comillas dobles **SOLO** del `"100.000"`, para que quede así:

```json
"impuesto" : {
    "currency" : "CLP",
    "amount" : 100.000
}
```

De antemano, muchas gracias:

Comment: ¿Y tiene que ser sí o sí con una expresión regular?

Comment: Otra pregunta, el valor "100.000" se supone es un valor flotante, porque si ese punto es separador de miles, entonces hay que eliminarlo de la expresión, ya que esto: `{"valor": 100.000}` es una cadena JSON válida de 100 con 3 decimales establecidos en 0.

Comment: @MauricioContreras pues en https://jsonlint.com/ dice que si es una cadena JSON válida... pero tal como indicas, sera porque se cree que son decimales

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esta expresión:

```js
json = '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "100.000" }}'
const regex = /"(-|)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)"/g 
json = json.replace(regex, '$1$2')
console.log(json)
```

Está sacada de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653496/10382744). Léete sus explicaciones en todo caso (que son ninguna,je).

## Actualización:

**Precaución**: Tal como indica @MauricioContreras en los comentarios de la pregunta, hay que tener atención con la dotación de punto, pues si se corresponde con el separador decimal la solución anterior es aún válida. En caso contrario, es decir, si el punto se corresponde con el separador de miles, la solución anterior no es válida.

### Otra solución

(gracias al aporte de @MauricioContreras en los comentarios)

```js
json = '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "100.000" }}'
const obj = JSON.parse(json)
obj.impuesto.amount = parseFloat(obj.impuesto.amount)
json = JSON.stringify(obj)
console.log(json)
```

> Esto hace el trabajo sin la recarga de una expresión regular, haciendo
> más evidente la intención o propósito durante el proceso. Permite
> capturar casos en que el campo en cuestión no exista o no sea posible
> convertir en valor numérico.

En el caso que ese punto fuera de miles, o quizás tambien hubieran una coma representando el separador decimal, se podría hacer así:

```js
json = '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "100.000,05" }}'
const obj = JSON.parse(json)
obj.impuesto.amount = parseFloat(obj.impuesto.amount.replace(/[.]/g,'').replace(/[,]/g,'.'))
json = JSON.stringify(obj)
console.log(json)
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN - SIN REGEXP**

Y en caso de que no desees usar una expresión regular de ninguna manera, puedes hacer lo siguiente: separar la cadena por comas y puntos.

Sin saber el formato recibido, y sólo especulando que el mismo implica cifras monetarias, en general podemos eliminar los puntos de separación de miles y la coma de separación decimal ([Sistema de numeración decimal - Normativa Internacional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numeraci%C3%B3n_decimal)) usando sólo métodos de cadena y de Arrays.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const numStringToNumber = str => {
  // separamos la parte entera de la decimal (si la hubiere)
  const valor = str.split(',');
  // eliminamos los puntos de separación de miles
  valor[0] = valor[0].split('.').join('');
  // retornamos el valor numérico usando parseFloat
  // usamos punto como separación decimal
  return parseFloat(valor.join('.'));
}

const jsonList = [
  '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "100.000,05" }}',
  '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "100.000" }}',
  '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "not valid" }}',
  '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "0,05" }}',
];

jsonList.forEach(json => {
  const obj = JSON.parse(json);
  obj.impuesto.amount = numStringToNumber(obj.impuesto.amount);
  json = JSON.stringify(obj)
  console.log(json);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top:0;
}
```

He implementado la lógica dentro de una función para poder reutilizarla si hiciera falta. En ningún momento se usa una expresión regular para la tarea, pero esto no significa que sea infalible. La implementación se ha escrito basado en una suposición sobre el formato de cadena recibido en el campo `amount`.

Comment: Esto: `const obj = JSON.parse(json);` y luego `obj.impuesto.amount = parseFloat(obj.impuesto.amount);` y por último `json = JSON.stringify(obj);`, hace el trabajo sin la recarga de una expresión regular, haciendo más evidente la intención o propósito durante el proceso. Permite capturar casos en que el campo en cuestión no exista o no sea posible convertir en valor numérico. Igual, tu respuesta atiende a la petición del OP, de eso no cabe duda. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Pues mira que lo habia intentado, pero no se me ocurrio lo del parseFloat, tan solo parsear y stringify tal cual... ahora entiendo porque, gracias. ¿Agrego tu aporte a la respuesta como una segunda solución o la agregas tu como respuesta?  Lo que prefieras.

Comment: Claro, pero toma en cuenta el segundo comentario que dejé en la pregunta.

Comment: jeje,. bueno, es que tampoco me queria matar tanto... el OP apenas ha hecho ningun esfuerzo y por eso ni me molesté en comprender y explicar la solución sacada del otro sitio

Comment: Hay un truco sencillo para lograr el valor que no sea decimal. Si quieres, luego que edites tu respuesta, agrego el truco para hacer la respuesta aún más completa. ;)

Comment: Ale, ya está... no se si es el mismo truco, pero hace poco lo he usado en otro lugar y funciona

Comment: XD, nuevamente una expresión regular. Vale, pero se puede hacer sin ellas. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Si quito la expresión regular y el número es, por ejemplo, 100.000.000,05 se me convierte a 100000 solamente pues tan solo coge el primer punto con el `replace('.','')`. Tal como dice la documentacion: *Si el patrón es una cadena, sólo la primera coincidencia será reemplazada.*

Answer (score 1):

Este regex elimina `"` que esté inmediatamente antes  después de un dígito, puede no funcionar para algunos casos, como que exista una palabra `key10` o `amount1`.

```js
json = '{"impuesto" : { "currency" : "CLP", "amount" : "100.000" }}'
const regex = /(?<=\d)"|"(?=\d)/g 
json = json.replace(regex, '')
console.log(json)
```

Comment: No sabemos si la representación de cadena del valor que se muestra en la pregunta indica punto decimal o punto de separación de miles. En caso de que sea lo segundo y se reciba una cadena de tipo: `"100.000,05"`, el procedimiento que describes usando una RegEx dejaría un JSON inválido. De todas formas tu respuesta funciona bastante bien para casos muy bien definidos. Saludos